# jquery.validate() trigger an event to check if a field in the form is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-file-upload

im using jquery validate and I would like to know if there is a way to check the validation only for one field of my form before calling the validation method of all of its fields:

```
var validator = $("#form").validate();
validator.form()
```

I want to do this because when the user uploads a file this one is uploaded to the server automatically, so i would like to validate the file extension before uploading the file to the server.

So i would like to have something like:

In my HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="linkIcon" name="linkIcon" data-url="/server/upload" required extension="jpg">
```

And in my JS:

```
        $('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
                   if($this).valid()){
                   //Do stuff...
                   }
            });
```

**Update:** Ok that worked well, but now i need to abort the file upload

this is what i have Im using jquery fileupload

```
$(function () {
    $('#linkIcon').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
            if(!$('#linkIcon').valid()){
                alert("invalid extension");
                $(this)[0].abort(); 
            } 
        },
 done: function (e, data) {
        //SUCCESS
        alert("file uploaded");
        },
    replaceFileInput: false
});
});
```

Comment: `if($(this).valid())` should be fine - there is a syntax error in your code

Comment: [As per the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) you can use the `.valid()` method on individual elements as well as the whole form.

Comment: that worked for me, thanks now im dealing with setting the 'beforeSend' paramter in my jquery File function in order to abort the upload if its not valid

Comment: Voting to close on the typographical error reason, because the only thing wrong is a missing `(`.  Basically the OP asks and then answers his own question.

Comment: well the thig is that i didnt know i can use that method because im new using this plugin, anyway please see the update and if u can help me i will appreciate it

Comment: Please edit your OP to explain where you got this `.fileupload()` method.  How are we supposed to know which plugins you're using if you don't tell us?

Comment: I just updated the OP plese note im using jquery file upload sorry for not including that part.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the extension of the file before calling the .valid() function.
jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/6mX4Q/)

```
 $('input[type=file]').change(function (e) {

    var fileName = $(this).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');//Gets the file name
    var isCorrectExtension = false;
    if (fileName != null) {
        var extension = fileName.substr((fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)).toLowerCase();
        if (extension === 'jpg' || extension === 'jpeg')
            isCorrectExtension = true;
    }

    if (isCorrectExtension) {
        //Do stuff...
    }
});
```

Comment: Um, what's the point of going through all this when we already have a jQuery Validation rule called [`extension`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/) that checks for valid file extensions?  In other words, why are you manually checking the file extension before using the validation plugin to automatically check the file extension?  And yes, the OP is using the `extension` rule as per his HTML attributes.